# How to resize a image to each site on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, css, mouseover

Is there a option in JavaScript or CSS to resize a image so that the image is growing out? So that the centerposition of the image is the same on mouseover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to able to center the image horizontally and vertically. This can be done using a wrapper div on the image with `display: table-cell`, `text-align: center`, and `vertical-align: middle`, and then applying some extra styles to the image on `:hover`.

See this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jblasco/6qVnB/

Optionally, rather than using `display: table-cell`, you could manually figure out some margins or a combination of `position: relative` and `top` to reposition the image on hover.

Example using this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jblasco/fvqzR/2/

Answer (score 0):

For a smooth effect I recommend incorporating [CSS3 transitions and transformations (see the section "2. Animating your Transforms"](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/) combined with [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com), this will allow an image to grow gradually and give a much more elegant effect than a straight forward `hover`.

I use Modernizr to ensure that the CSS3 effects I use can be consistent across all browsers to even if they don't support and being written in JavaScript it fits within the scope of the solution you're looking for.

I hope this helps you.